# Facebook authentication and own authentication

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-login

I have a site with classic registration / authentication.

I added the ability to access via facebook or google but I have a doubt .. how can I avoid the doubling of the account?

I mean ... in the case where a user is already registered with the classical recording I should associate his user charges to that of facebook In case the user is new I would still give him the opportunity to register via facebook (basic and quick registration which derives the main data such as name surname email) but he can also do the normal login with username and password on the site ...

How to behave normally in these cases? Hello and thanks, Stefano

Answer (score 0):

There's really not any (friendly) way you can prevent a user from registering on a system multiple times. Providing multiple authentication methods just makes that even easier to do (both deliberately and by accident).

I don't think there's any particular way to deal with this, though you could always warn a user on registration that they may have already registered via Facebook, etc.